# Calling Utc.Now on a Utc timed Server

Tags: c#

Please someone drop some knowledge on me. I am in the EST zone, and I have a Azure site that uses UTC time. Lets say its 5:08 time on the server. What happens if I call Utc.Now on that server? Would it give me 5:08 or sometime like 10:08. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `UTC` time is calculated based on the Timezone offset specified in the system. if it is configured to `+0 GMT`, you'll get same time.

Answer (score 1):

UTC time is meant to be a constant reference. Calling `DateTime.UtcNow` Makes a simple translation of DateTime.Now to UTC time using your local timezone and daylight savings information.

Internally, dates are stored as 64-bit integers. That number represents the number of nanoseconds since 1/1/0001 in UTC/GMT (they mean the same thing). The Ticks property returns this value. If you divide it by 10,000 you can see it in milliseconds which is a little easier to get your head around.

The code

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1, 1, 1).Ticks);
```

always produces 0 in the output window. The code

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(1, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime().Ticks);
```

,in EST, adds 180000000000 to the internally stored date value because that is the number of nanoseconds in 5 hours. Thus, creating a new date where a change of -180000000000 (-05:00) is needed to put it back into local time. Looking at it from 1/1/0001 always helps me to visualize what I am trying to do.

In answer to your question, when you call `DateTime.UtcNow` on a server that is configured to be in GMT timezone, there is no conversion to or from local and UTC times because they are always the same. In fact `DateTime.UtcNow` should return the same thing as `DateTime.Now` if the server believes it is in that timezone.

If you store a date in UTC time, you are storing a reference to a single point in time that can be translated to the SAME point in time, in any other timezone in the world.

I hope this answer helps some.